# Django: Can I use HttpResponseRedirect() and give it any arguments to be rendered on this page?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, forms, httpresponse

I have a Django form which upon validation I want to redirect to a success page. I start at "localhost/upload", submit my form, if it is validated I want to go to localhost/upload/success. The following code works, I just want to be able to pass a context dictionary with some variables in there to render to the page. I can only do this using (hashed out in the views.py code below)

```
return render(request, 'results/success.html', context)
```

but this returns to localhost/upload, but with my success.html template - i want to go to upload/success.

Here is my code:

views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='/')
def upload(request):

    """ Upload panel or results.
    """

    if request.method == 'POST':

        paneluploadform = PanelUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if paneluploadform.is_valid():

            paneluploadform.upload()

            context = {'hi': 'helloasdgja'}

            # return render(request, 'results/success.html', context)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('success')


        else:
            # print(paneluploadform.errors.as_text)
            pass

   else:

        paneluploadform = PanelUploadForm()
        context = {'paneluploadform': paneluploadform}

        return render(request, 'results/upload.html', context)


 @login_required(login_url='/')
 def success(request):

     """ Success view
     """

     return render(request, 'results/success.html')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^upload/$', upload),
    url(r'^upload/success/', success)
]
```

I can use the hashed out return render() line to give my test context, but this returns to "localhost:8000/upload"

I want to go to localhost:800/upload/success, but get information from upload view and redirect to upload/success. Can I pass a context arg to HttpResponseRedirect or is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session variables are useful for passing information between pages/views.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/

Ian Clelland does a good job of highlighting your options here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8931063/4928578